# How to get the value of check box in OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am new to OS X App development. I have a number of check boxes in the App. I need to store the values as 1's and 0's depending on whether the check box is selected or not. How do I get the value to an NSInteger variable say "NSInteger sampleValue".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create IBAction and connect to checkbox

```
-(IBAction)checkBoxState : (id)sender;
{
    NSLog(@"state %d", [sender state]);
}
```

If you have multiple checkbox, connect all checkbox to same IBAction method. change tag value of checkbox
[image]

```
-(IBAction)checkBoxState : (id)sender;
{
    if (0==[sender tag]) {
        NSLog(@"1st checkbox state %d", [sender state]);
    }
    else    if (1==[sender tag]) {
        NSLog(@"2nd checkbox state %d", [sender state]);
    }
    else    if (2==[sender tag]) {
        NSLog(@"3rd checkbox state %d", [sender state]);
    }


}
```

Take a look at [sample project](https://www.idrivesync.com/share/view?k=360yZntCKep83m6ew0AI5aNVFnXn5JXg).

Comment: You can also create an IBOutlet to the checkbox (a named variable that lets you get a reference to it at runtime) and ask it directly, rather than rely on the target/action mechanism. The "best" approach depends on your goal and overall design.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get `NSInteger` value use `[checkbox state]`. It can be done like this:

```
NSInteger integValue = [checkBoxOutlet state];

NSLog(@"%li", integValue); //Show value on screen
```

*checkBoxOutlet* is Your checkbox Outlet in header file.

Comment: even if it is checked or not

Comment: @NidhinBalakrishnan: Then you didn't connect your outlets. A disconnected outlet, or an outlet that is connected in a nib you haven't loaded yet, holds the value `nil`, like any other instance variable or property that hasn't yet been set. Any message to `nil` returns zero.

Comment: @PeterHosey : You are right. I missed that part. i corrected that. tnks

Answer (score 3):

You can find as to this: (check1 is the property name for checkBox)

```
NSLog(@"%ld",[_check1 state]);//will give -1, 0 or 1, as mixed, off or on.
```

Also, if you want to be more futuristic (i.e. if in future the value of 1 or 0 or -1 is changed, then use these enums )

```
if ([_check1 state]==NSOnState) {
    NSLog(@"ON-Checked");
}
else if([_check1 state]==NSOffState){
    NSLog(@"OFF-UnChecked");
}
else if([_check1 state]==NSMixedState){
    NSLog(@"OFF-MixedChecked");
}
```